# find and replace string in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to replace stings in a file using regular expression in python.
The code I have come up with is

```
import re

s=open('C:/Users/Tamal/Desktop/py_regex_sample.txt', 'r')
re.sub(r'(\w)+\s(\w)+', r'<fname>\1</fname>\n<sname>\2</sname>', s, 0, flags=re.I)
s.close()
```

The file contains two lines consisting two names

```
"John Hammond
Joey Mercury"
```

But it shows an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really wanna use "re" for this? Wouldn't the normal string replace method solve your purpose?

Comment: The second parameter of [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) must be a string, not a regex pattern.

Comment: When you say "it shows an error", always **always** include the content of error, in its entirety. That information prints for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need re to replace strings.

You can use `replace()` like so:

```
>>> s = "This is a string."
>>> s = s.replace("This", "That")
>>> print(s)
That is a string.
```

Now, if you don't know what you need to replace you can parse the whole string manually or find with re.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is giving an error because you are passing whole file as third parameter which is not accepted by `re.sub()`. The third parameter should be `string` and not file. So it is causing an error.

If you want to do `inplace` replacement, you should try this

```
import re,fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('input_file.txt', inplace=True): 
    print(re.sub(r'(\w+)\s(\w+)', r'<fname>\1</fname>\n<sname>\2</sname>', line.strip("\n"), flags=re.I))
```

Comment: what are the functions of "inplace="True" and "line.strip"?

Comment: @TamalBanerjee `line.strip("\n")` is used to remove the trailing new line and `inplace=True` means read a file and overwrite in the same file

Comment: @TamalBanerjee quoting from documentation about `inplace=True` :- `if the keyword argument inplace=True is passed to fileinput.input() or to the FileInput constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced silently).`

Comment: rock321987, thank you very much for your support, really appreciate your help, and one more thing, is it necessary to use the "line.strip" in the example text that I posted and what other options can I use in place of it?

Comment: If you don't use `line.strip()`, then you will get extra new lines in output..try it yourself removing the `strip`

Comment: I did that, but it returned an error   "TypeError: sub() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'"

Comment: @TamalBanerjee `print(re.sub(r'(\w+)\s(\w+)', r'<fname>\1</fname>\n<sname>\2</sname>', line, flags=re.I))` try this..you are removing third parameter

Comment: @TamalBanerjee whatever you will `print` inside the loop, it will directly be written to that file and cannot be printed on `console`

Comment: it works, but extra blank new lines are formed, and why is the "print" statement used here

Comment: that's why I was telling to use `strip`..`print` statement redirects whatever is there inside `print` to the current file

Comment: @TamalBanerjee is there any problem with using `strip`?

Comment: well then what about I want to replace certain strings in a large text using regular expression in the same method, I only want to replace all strings selected by the pattern but don't want to insert any new line or anything, suppose I want to replace all digits with a tag "<d>the digit</d>" in a file containing strings like "this is a 10 year old dog" and dont want it to become like "this is a <d>10</d>"....a new line and then "year old dog". I want the file to be just as it was before but with the tag <d/> on each numbers of the entire file.

Comment: @TamalBanerjee I think you should read the file line by line and perform whatever as you like

Comment: @TamalBanerjee I answered as per your question..Now you are adding more and more conditions..

Comment: @TamalBanerjee If you will use correctly, it will print correctly..try this `print(re.sub(r'(.*)\b(\d+)\b(.*)', r'\1<d>\2</d>\3', line.strip("\n"), flags=re.I))` with your input `this is a 10 year old dog`..It will work as expected..No new lines as you are saying